# Is there a way to allow users to customize their feed view?

Tags: categories

I run an aggregate site and it produces lots of posts throughout the day. Is there a way for me to allow users to log in and select what category shows up on their feed? So they could choose between "native" and "custom" essentially. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question shows that you have not really made much effort to research the problem.  The short answer is yes, but a detailed answer would not be of much value to others on this platform.  Furthermore, similar questions (with broader applications) have already been [answered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33893/front-end-user-meta-options-for-users).

Comment: It's not so much I haven't made the effort, it's that I am brand new to this and am only vaguely family with code. This forum is somewhere I generally don't wander into for that reason. As soon as it goes into that without an essentially laypersons explanation I get overwhelmed. Would you happen to have any recommendations as to the best place to start? Thank you for taking the time to respond and sorry if I happened to annoy you

Comment: not annoyed :)  am just trying to give you some tips in understanding what kind of questions are likely answered.  Where to start for a beginner...you need to learn some PHP coding, so I would recommend an online tutorial in that, especially on how page requests are handled by PHP code.  Next you should get to grip with the WordPress framework, a tutorial on how to manipulate user custom data and how to get the current logged in user.  Finally, a tutorial on feeds in WordPress, and how to customise feeds.